# Type 'TEntity' doesn't match expected type '???'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, repository-pattern

I've built a generic repository interface off which hang a number of entity specific repository interfaces. Mirroring this structure are a number of concrete repository classes.

I'm getting the following error in my base Repository class:

[image: Error location]

> Type 'TEntity' doesn't match expected type '???'. 
>   Method 'GetAll' cannot implement method from interface '...IRepository<TEntity, TIdentity>'. Return type should be 'System.Collections.Generic.List<???>'.

The minified interface/class structure is as follows:

**IRepository**:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity, in TIdentity> where TEntity : IEntity<TIdentity>
{
    ...
    List<TEntity> GetAll();
    ...
}
```

**Repository**:

```
internal class Repository<TEntity, TIdentity> : IRepository<TEntity, TIdentity>
        where TEntity : class, IEntity<TIdentity>
{
    ...
    protected DbSet<TEntity> Set => _set ?? (_set = _context.Set<TEntity>());

    public List<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return Set.ToList();
    }
    ...
}
```

**IRoleRepository**:

```
public interface IRoleRepository : IRepository<Role, Guid>
{
    ...
    Role FindByName(string roleName);
    ...
}
```

**RoleRepository**:

```
internal class RoleRepository : Repository<Role, Guid>, IRoleRepository
{
    ...
    public Role FindByName(string roleName)
    {
        return Set.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == roleName);
    }
    ...
}
```

This has a knock on effect in my consuming classes where doing a `RoleRepository.GetAll()` returns a `List<???>` rather than a `List<Role>` as I expected.

**Edit - Entity definitions...**

**IEntity**:

```
public interface IEntity<T>
{
    T Id { get; set; }
    byte[] Version { get; set; }
}
```

**Entity**:

```
public abstract class Entity<T> : IEntity<T>
{
    public T Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Version { get; set; }
}
```

**Role**:

```
public class Role : Entity<Guid>
{
    private ICollection<User> _users;
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Users
    {
        get { return _users ?? (_users = new List<User>()); }
        set { _users = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `Set.ToList<TEntity>();`

Comment: Thanks, tried that but it doesn't resolve the error. Also ReSharper tells me `Type argument specification is redundant`.

Comment: Is your TEntity implementing all interfaces from where statement? I think TEntity is not implementing IEntity<TIdentity> as TEntity is EF type. Try remove where from that repository.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `TEntity` class is not implementing that interface: `IEntity<TIdentity>`

Depends if your are using `CodeFirst` at `EntityFramework` or `ModelFirst` you have other options to go with:

`ModelFirst`: you can use `Model.tt` file to specify implementation of interfaces you need.

`CodeFirst`: just implement that interface in the model class.

Third option is just get rid of that `where TEntity : IEntity<TIdentity>` only if your are not using anything from that interface of course.

Comment: I've added my entity model definitions to the question. `Role` inherits from `Entity<>` which implements `IEntity<>`. EF doesn't come into it at this stage as I'm purely dealing with the entities and I like to keep persistence completely separate.